# For-each loop capability with dynamic arrays without VBA?

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, foreach

I've been trying to figure this out for hours and have tried lots of ways to get this to work (e.g., Let, Offset, Countifs, Lambda, helper columns, etc.), but can't crack this nut yet.

Here's a sample of the spreadsheet.  NOTE: this is greatly simplified.  The actual spreadsheet has many class start dates, many different events, and very different class structures.

[image]

Each team has multiple classes with different start dates.  Each team also has a completely different class structure (different events, different timelines).  Tstart=number of days from class start date the event occurs.  Duration=number of days the event lasts.  The "Class start dates" and "Class structure" sections are given, but the entire "Schedule" section needs to be calculated, and it needs to be a running list as shown.

The process order would be:

If "Class start date" isn't blank, then calculate the class schedule based on that team's class structure.  (This part I have, but I'm sure there are better ways to do it than what I have).

Then, check one cell below the previous "Class start date" and repeat the above with the output being placed immediately below the previous output.  This is the iteration part I can't figure out.

Dynamic arrays haven't played nice because each team schedule has a different number of rows based on having a different number of events.

Haven't been able to figure out how to use Offset or other functions to iterate within a single formula.

Would sure appreciate any help!!!

Here's the given data in markdown table format.

| Team | Class | Class start date |  | Team | Event | Tstart | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Yellow | 1 | 1/15/2024 |  | Yellow | Paperwork | -10 | 2 |
| Blue | 1 | 1/20/2024 |  | Yellow | Sign in | 0 | 1 |
| Orange | 1 | 1/30/2024 |  | Yellow | Interviews | 2 | 2 |
| Yellow | 2 | 2/15/2024 |  | Blue | Paperwork | -8 | 2 |
|  |  |  |  | Blue | Sign in | 0 | 1 |
|  |  |  |  | Blue | Interviews | 4 | 2 |
|  |  |  |  | Blue | Farewell | 6 | 1 |
|  |  |  |  | Orange | Paperwork | -6 | 1 |
|  |  |  |  | Orange | Sign in | 0 | 1 |
|  |  |  |  | Orange | Meeting | 3 | 1 |
|  |  |  |  | Orange | Interviews | 5 | 1 |

Comment: can you explain why a duration of 2 is `1/5/2024` to `1/7/2024` and a duration of 1 is `1/15/2024` to `1/15/2024`?

Comment: And, can you please put that data in markdown table format in the question so we can copy paste?

Comment: Apologies, the end dates were off because I just quickly hand-entered them.  Corrected in the markdown table format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Dynamic Arrays' Loop Capability

- When you get tired of figuring out how to do it with other functions (I did!), the `DROP/REDUCE/VSTACK` combo comes to the rescue.
- It might seem mindboggling at the moment but once you get a hang of it, you'll see that many questions can easily be answered with it.
- The issue with it is that it is rather slow on large datasets (due to the repeated stacking) hence it is avoided whenever possible.

```
=LET(cdata,A2:C5,edata,E2:H12,
    DROP(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(ROWS(cdata)),LAMBDA(rr,r,LET(
        ef,FILTER(edata,CHOOSECOLS(edata,1)=INDEX(cdata,r,1)),
        a,TAKE(ef,,2),
        b,IF(SEQUENCE(ROWS(ef)),INDEX(cdata,r,2)),
        c,INDEX(cdata,r,3)+CHOOSECOLS(ef,3),
        d,c+CHOOSECOLS(ef,4)-1,
        VSTACK(rr,HSTACK(a,b,c,d))))),1))
```

[image]

**Edit (Switched `Event` and `Class` Columns)**

```
=LET(cdata,A2:C5,edata,E2:H12,
    DROP(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(ROWS(cdata)),LAMBDA(rr,r,LET(
        ef,FILTER(edata,CHOOSECOLS(edata,1)=INDEX(cdata,r,1)),
        a,CHOOSECOLS(ef,1),
        b,IF(SEQUENCE(ROWS(ef)),INDEX(cdata,r,2)),
        c,CHOOSECOLS(ef,2),
        d,INDEX(cdata,r,3)+CHOOSECOLS(ef,3),
        e,d+CHOOSECOLS(ef,4)-1,
        VSTACK(rr,HSTACK(a,b,c,d,e))))),1))
```

[image]

Comment: This works great, especially because I can define cdata and edata as tables.  The only thing is how can the calculated "Class" and "Event" columns be swapped in the output? The data has to be in this order from left to right: Team, Class, Event, Start date, End date.

Comment: Sorry, never noticed it. Added below,

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data with REDUCE:

```
=DROP(REDUCE(
    "",ROW(A2:C5),
        LAMBDA(y,z,
            VSTACK(y,
                LET(x,FILTER(E:H,E:E=INDEX(A:A,z)),
                HSTACK(
                    CHOOSECOLS(x,1,2),
                    INDEX(B:B,z)+CHOOSECOLS(x,3)*0,
                    INDEX(C:C,z)+CHOOSECOLS(x,3),
                    INDEX(C:C,z)+CHOOSECOLS(x,3)+CHOOSECOLS(x,4)-1)
                    )))),1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, here is a solution for Excel 2016:

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Team | Class | Class start date |  | Team | Event | Tstart | Duration |  | Formulas check | Rows needed | Progressive rows | Team index | Team | Class | Event index | Event | Start date | End date |
| Yellow | 1 | 45306 |  | Yellow | Paperwork | -10 | 2 |  | `=IF(COUNTA(N:N)<SUM(K:K)+1,"More rows","Rows ok")` | `=IF(A3="","",COUNTIF(E:E,A3))` | `=IF(K3="","",SUM($K$3:K3))` | `=IF(ROWS($M$3:M3)<MIN(K:K),1,IF(ROWS($M$3:M3)>SUM(K:K),"",MATCH(ROWS($M$3:M3),$L$3:L3,1)+1))` | `=IF(M3<>"",INDEX($A$3:A3,MAX(1,M2)),"")` | `=IF(M3<>"",INDEX($B$3:B3,MAX(1,M2)),"")` | `=IF(M3="","",AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(E:E)/(E:E=N3),COUNTIFS($N$3:N3,N3,$O$3:O3,O3)))` | `=IF(M3="","",INDEX(F:F,P3))` | `=IF(M3="","",INDEX(G:G,P3)+INDEX($C$3:C3,MAX(1,M2)))` | `=IF(M3="","",INDEX(H:H,P3)+R3-1)` |
| Blue | 1 | 45311 |  | Yellow | Sign in | 0 | 1 |  |  | `=IF(A4="","",COUNTIF(E:E,A4))` | `=IF(K4="","",SUM($K$3:K4))` | `=IF(ROWS($M$3:M4)<MIN(K:K),1,IF(ROWS($M$3:M4)>SUM(K:K),"",MATCH(ROWS($M$3:M4),$L$3:L4,1)+1))` | `=IF(M4<>"",INDEX($A$3:A4,MAX(1,M3)),"")` | `=IF(M4<>"",INDEX($B$3:B4,MAX(1,M3)),"")` | `=IF(M4="","",AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(E:E)/(E:E=N4),COUNTIFS($N$3:N4,N4,$O$3:O4,O4)))` | `=IF(M4="","",INDEX(F:F,P4))` | `=IF(M4="","",INDEX(G:G,P4)+INDEX($C$3:C4,MAX(1,M3)))` | `=IF(M4="","",INDEX(H:H,P4)+R4-1)` |
| Orange | 1 | 45321 |  | Yellow | Interviews | 2 | 2 |  |  | `=IF(A5="","",COUNTIF(E:E,A5))` | `=IF(K5="","",SUM($K$3:K5))` | `=IF(ROWS($M$3:M5)<MIN(K:K),1,IF(ROWS($M$3:M5)>SUM(K:K),"",MATCH(ROWS($M$3:M5),$L$3:L5,1)+1))` | `=IF(M5<>"",INDEX($A$3:A5,MAX(1,M4)),"")` | `=IF(M5<>"",INDEX($B$3:B5,MAX(1,M4)),"")` | `=IF(M5="","",AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(E:E)/(E:E=N5),COUNTIFS($N$3:N5,N5,$O$3:O5,O5)))` | `=IF(M5="","",INDEX(F:F,P5))` | `=IF(M5="","",INDEX(G:G,P5)+INDEX($C$3:C5,MAX(1,M4)))` | `=IF(M5="","",INDEX(H:H,P5)+R5-1)` |
| Yellow | 2 | 45337 |  | Blue | Paperwork | -8 | 2 |  |  | `=IF(A6="","",COUNTIF(E:E,A6))` | `=IF(K6="","",SUM($K$3:K6))` | `=IF(ROWS($M$3:M6)<MIN(K:K),1,IF(ROWS($M$3:M6)>SUM(K:K),"",MATCH(ROWS($M$3:M6),$L$3:L6,1)+1))` | `=IF(M6<>"",INDEX($A$3:A6,MAX(1,M5)),"")` | `=IF(M6<>"",INDEX($B$3:B6,MAX(1,M5)),"")` | `=IF(M6="","",AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(E:E)/(E:E=N6),COUNTIFS($N$3:N6,N6,$O$3:O6,O6)))` | `=IF(M6="","",INDEX(F:F,P6))` | `=IF(M6="","",INDEX(G:G,P6)+INDEX($C$3:C6,MAX(1,M5)))` | `=IF(M6="","",INDEX(H:H,P6)+R6-1)` |
|  |  |  |  | Blue | Sign in | 0 | 1 |  |  | `=IF(A7="","",COUNTIF(E:E,A7))` | `=IF(K7="","",SUM($K$3:K7))` | `=IF(ROWS($M$3:M7)<MIN(K:K),1,IF(ROWS($M$3:M7)>SUM(K:K),"",MATCH(ROWS($M$3:M7),$L$3:L7,1)+1))` | `=IF(M7<>"",INDEX($A$3:A7,MAX(1,M6)),"")` | `=IF(M7<>"",INDEX($B$3:B7,MAX(1,M6)),"")` | `=IF(M7="","",AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(E:E)/(E:E=N7),COUNTIFS($N$3:N7,N7,$O$3:O7,O7)))` | `=IF(M7="","",INDEX(F:F,P7))` | `=IF(M7="","",INDEX(G:G,P7)+INDEX($C$3:C7,MAX(1,M6)))` | `=IF(M7="","",INDEX(H:H,P7)+R7-1)` |
|  |  |  |  | Blue | Interviews | 4 | 2 |  |  | `=IF(A8="","",COUNTIF(E:E,A8))` | `=IF(K8="","",SUM($K$3:K8))` | `=IF(ROWS($M$3:M8)<MIN(K:K),1,IF(ROWS($M$3:M8)>SUM(K:K),"",MATCH(ROWS($M$3:M8),$L$3:L8,1)+1))` | `=IF(M8<>"",INDEX($A$3:A8,MAX(1,M7)),"")` | `=IF(M8<>"",INDEX($B$3:B8,MAX(1,M7)),"")` | `=IF(M8="","",AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(E:E)/(E:E=N8),COUNTIFS($N$3:N8,N8,$O$3:O8,O8)))` | `=IF(M8="","",INDEX(F:F,P8))` | `=IF(M8="","",INDEX(G:G,P8)+INDEX($C$3:C8,MAX(1,M7)))` | `=IF(M8="","",INDEX(H:H,P8)+R8-1)` |
|  |  |  |  | Blue | Farewell | 6 | 1 |  |  | `=IF(A9="","",COUNTIF(E:E,A9))` | `=IF(K9="","",SUM($K$3:K9))` | `=IF(ROWS($M$3:M9)<MIN(K:K),1,IF(ROWS($M$3:M9)>SUM(K:K),"",MATCH(ROWS($M$3:M9),$L$3:L9,1)+1))` | `=IF(M9<>"",INDEX($A$3:A9,MAX(1,M8)),"")` | `=IF(M9<>"",INDEX($B$3:B9,MAX(1,M8)),"")` | `=IF(M9="","",AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(E:E)/(E:E=N9),COUNTIFS($N$3:N9,N9,$O$3:O9,O9)))` | `=IF(M9="","",INDEX(F:F,P9))` | `=IF(M9="","",INDEX(G:G,P9)+INDEX($C$3:C9,MAX(1,M8)))` | `=IF(M9="","",INDEX(H:H,P9)+R9-1)` |
|  |  |  |  | Orange | Paperwork | -6 | 1 |  |  | `=IF(A10="","",COUNTIF(E:E,A10))` | `=IF(K10="","",SUM($K$3:K10))` | `=IF(ROWS($M$3:M10)<MIN(K:K),1,IF(ROWS($M$3:M10)>SUM(K:K),"",MATCH(ROWS($M$3:M10),$L$3:L10,1)+1))` | `=IF(M10<>"",INDEX($A$3:A10,MAX(1,M9)),"")` | `=IF(M10<>"",INDEX($B$3:B10,MAX(1,M9)),"")` | `=IF(M10="","",AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(E:E)/(E:E=N10),COUNTIFS($N$3:N10,N10,$O$3:O10,O10)))` | `=IF(M10="","",INDEX(F:F,P10))` | `=IF(M10="","",INDEX(G:G,P10)+INDEX($C$3:C10,MAX(1,M9)))` | `=IF(M10="","",INDEX(H:H,P10)+R10-1)` |
|  |  |  |  | Orange | Sign in | 0 | 1 |  |  | `=IF(A11="","",COUNTIF(E:E,A11))` | `=IF(K11="","",SUM($K$3:K11))` | `=IF(ROWS($M$3:M11)<MIN(K:K),1,IF(ROWS($M$3:M11)>SUM(K:K),"",MATCH(ROWS($M$3:M11),$L$3:L11,1)+1))` | `=IF(M11<>"",INDEX($A$3:A11,MAX(1,M10)),"")` | `=IF(M11<>"",INDEX($B$3:B11,MAX(1,M10)),"")` | `=IF(M11="","",AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(E:E)/(E:E=N11),COUNTIFS($N$3:N11,N11,$O$3:O11,O11)))` | `=IF(M11="","",INDEX(F:F,P11))` | `=IF(M11="","",INDEX(G:G,P11)+INDEX($C$3:C11,MAX(1,M10)))` | `=IF(M11="","",INDEX(H:H,P11)+R11-1)` |
|  |  |  |  | Orange | Meeting | 3 | 1 |  |  | `=IF(A12="","",COUNTIF(E:E,A12))` | `=IF(K12="","",SUM($K$3:K12))` | `=IF(ROWS($M$3:M12)<MIN(K:K),1,IF(ROWS($M$3:M12)>SUM(K:K),"",MATCH(ROWS($M$3:M12),$L$3:L12,1)+1))` | `=IF(M12<>"",INDEX($A$3:A12,MAX(1,M11)),"")` | `=IF(M12<>"",INDEX($B$3:B12,MAX(1,M11)),"")` | `=IF(M12="","",AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(E:E)/(E:E=N12),COUNTIFS($N$3:N12,N12,$O$3:O12,O12)))` | `=IF(M12="","",INDEX(F:F,P12))` | `=IF(M12="","",INDEX(G:G,P12)+INDEX($C$3:C12,MAX(1,M11)))` | `=IF(M12="","",INDEX(H:H,P12)+R12-1)` |
|  |  |  |  | Orange | Interviews | 5 | 1 |  |  | `=IF(A13="","",COUNTIF(E:E,A13))` | `=IF(K13="","",SUM($K$3:K13))` | `=IF(ROWS($M$3:M13)<MIN(K:K),1,IF(ROWS($M$3:M13)>SUM(K:K),"",MATCH(ROWS($M$3:M13),$L$3:L13,1)+1))` | `=IF(M13<>"",INDEX($A$3:A13,MAX(1,M12)),"")` | `=IF(M13<>"",INDEX($B$3:B13,MAX(1,M12)),"")` | `=IF(M13="","",AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(E:E)/(E:E=N13),COUNTIFS($N$3:N13,N13,$O$3:O13,O13)))` | `=IF(M13="","",INDEX(F:F,P13))` | `=IF(M13="","",INDEX(G:G,P13)+INDEX($C$3:C13,MAX(1,M12)))` | `=IF(M13="","",INDEX(H:H,P13)+R13-1)` |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | `=IF(A14="","",COUNTIF(E:E,A14))` | `=IF(K14="","",SUM($K$3:K14))` | `=IF(ROWS($M$3:M14)<MIN(K:K),1,IF(ROWS($M$3:M14)>SUM(K:K),"",MATCH(ROWS($M$3:M14),$L$3:L14,1)+1))` | `=IF(M14<>"",INDEX($A$3:A14,MAX(1,M13)),"")` | `=IF(M14<>"",INDEX($B$3:B14,MAX(1,M13)),"")` | `=IF(M14="","",AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(E:E)/(E:E=N14),COUNTIFS($N$3:N14,N14,$O$3:O14,O14)))` | `=IF(M14="","",INDEX(F:F,P14))` | `=IF(M14="","",INDEX(G:G,P14)+INDEX($C$3:C14,MAX(1,M13)))` | `=IF(M14="","",INDEX(H:H,P14)+R14-1)` |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | `=IF(A15="","",COUNTIF(E:E,A15))` | `=IF(K15="","",SUM($K$3:K15))` | `=IF(ROWS($M$3:M15)<MIN(K:K),1,IF(ROWS($M$3:M15)>SUM(K:K),"",MATCH(ROWS($M$3:M15),$L$3:L15,1)+1))` | `=IF(M15<>"",INDEX($A$3:A15,MAX(1,M14)),"")` | `=IF(M15<>"",INDEX($B$3:B15,MAX(1,M14)),"")` | `=IF(M15="","",AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(E:E)/(E:E=N15),COUNTIFS($N$3:N15,N15,$O$3:O15,O15)))` | `=IF(M15="","",INDEX(F:F,P15))` | `=IF(M15="","",INDEX(G:G,P15)+INDEX($C$3:C15,MAX(1,M14)))` | `=IF(M15="","",INDEX(H:H,P15)+R15-1)` |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | `=IF(A16="","",COUNTIF(E:E,A16))` | `=IF(K16="","",SUM($K$3:K16))` | `=IF(ROWS($M$3:M16)<MIN(K:K),1,IF(ROWS($M$3:M16)>SUM(K:K),"",MATCH(ROWS($M$3:M16),$L$3:L16,1)+1))` | `=IF(M16<>"",INDEX($A$3:A16,MAX(1,M15)),"")` | `=IF(M16<>"",INDEX($B$3:B16,MAX(1,M15)),"")` | `=IF(M16="","",AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(E:E)/(E:E=N16),COUNTIFS($N$3:N16,N16,$O$3:O16,O16)))` | `=IF(M16="","",INDEX(F:F,P16))` | `=IF(M16="","",INDEX(G:G,P16)+INDEX($C$3:C16,MAX(1,M15)))` | `=IF(M16="","",INDEX(H:H,P16)+R16-1)` |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | `=IF(A17="","",COUNTIF(E:E,A17))` | `=IF(K17="","",SUM($K$3:K17))` | `=IF(ROWS($M$3:M17)<MIN(K:K),1,IF(ROWS($M$3:M17)>SUM(K:K),"",MATCH(ROWS($M$3:M17),$L$3:L17,1)+1))` | `=IF(M17<>"",INDEX($A$3:A17,MAX(1,M16)),"")` | `=IF(M17<>"",INDEX($B$3:B17,MAX(1,M16)),"")` | `=IF(M17="","",AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(E:E)/(E:E=N17),COUNTIFS($N$3:N17,N17,$O$3:O17,O17)))` | `=IF(M17="","",INDEX(F:F,P17))` | `=IF(M17="","",INDEX(G:G,P17)+INDEX($C$3:C17,MAX(1,M16)))` | `=IF(M17="","",INDEX(H:H,P17)+R17-1)` |

By the way: make sure that you don't have to discard any date (holidays, days off, etc).